# Nginx with uwsgi

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I am using nginx with uwsgi.
I want to serve an html page but with an image attached to it dynamically. So the page will have some contents (generated dynamically) and the image at the top.
Please let me know how can I do it.
I am able to serve the page with contents alone.

Note: I am not using anything else (like Flask, Django etc.).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider to use flask. It's simple and light weight works with Uwsgi and Nfgnx well. You may not need to spend long on http://flask.pocoo.org/ tutorials to hack together a template that serves what you want.

Comment: Configure nginx to also serve static files from a specific dir, put your static image file in it, and refer to it from your dynamic HTML.

Comment: Thanks jwalker. @darwindave thanks for the idea but we cant use anything else.